# Detecting Similar Varieties of Apples Using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm starting a project where I want to detect various types of apples (Granny Smith, Gala, Fuji, Honey Crisp, etc) + quality checking in still images using OpenCV.

I've conducting some searching that using SURF for feature extraction and Neural Network for the object classification could be good combination. But since various apple types bear similar features, could it be possibly done with those algorithm? Or are there any better methods?

Thank you.

Comment: I doubt it.  I even have a hard time determining what the different apples are and the reason why is exactly as you say.  All apples have a very similar shape.  The only things that I can think of that differentiate between the different apples are the size and perhaps the colour.  SIFT / SURF is good for differentiating between objects that are significantly different.  However, if you try to use this for getting apples, it certainly can detect them, but I'm fairly certain that it won't have the discriminative power to tell you **what kind** of apple it is, only that it is an apple.

Comment: I agree that SURF/SIFT are probably not the way to go. Do you have a segmentation module? I would probably compare texture and color histogram features and train a classifier based on those features.

Comment: If you have enough images (>= 10K), try convolutional neural network.